# How to read a pom.xml and get 'artifactId' in Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

How we can read a pom.xml and get the 'artifactId' 'groupId' etc in the GruntFile.js.

'xml-parser'- I saw in the NPM but how can I use that in GruntFile.js , Anyone has any example . I am very new to Grunt .

Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search npm registry for XML parser

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var parse = require('xml-parser'); 
var xml = fs.readFileSync('example.xml', 'utf8'); 
var obj = parse(xml);
```

obj is your parsed xml

Comment: Thanks for your comment . I am new to Grunt , how can I use 'xml-parser' in Grunt file .

Comment: eagerToLearn already knows about npm xml parser packages, but does not know how to use them in combination with Grunt

Comment: @Molda Sorry I did not notice that. Therefore I correct my statement and upvoted your anwer

Comment: Molda and ooxi , sorry about the confusion . I have seen xml parser before in NPM but i did not mention that in my question, after seeing @Molda comments I modified it . Thanks guys ..

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use 'pom-parser' (https://github.com/intuit/node-pom-parser)
Install the package:

```
npm install --save node-pom-parser
```

then, in the grunt file

```
var ext = require('pom-parser'); 
var pom = ext.parsePom({ filePath: "pom.xml"});

var artifactId = pom.artifactId;
console.log(artifactId)
module.exports = function(grunt) {
//GRUNT ....
}
```

<s>But it won't work in Windows.</s> https://github.com/marcellodesales/node-pom-parser/issues/1
**UPDATE:** `pom-parser` has been refactored and is now compatible with Windows (see resolution on linked issue).